# Python Scapy gnuplot issue

Tags: python, gnuplot, scapy

I'm trying to draw a image from scapy as visual result of a particular scan.

This is what I've done:

```
[1]: a,b=sr(IP(dst="target")/TCP(sport=[RandShort()]*1000))
[2]: a.plot(lambda x:x[1].id)
```

I'm getting the following response but not graphic image although I have all gnuplot libraries installed properly. I mean when I'm starting scapy I'm not getting any complains about gnuplot or such.

```
<Gnuplot._Gnuplot.Gnuplot instance at 0x4f244d0>
```

So, how can I see actually the generated image?

Comment: Does `a.show()` work?

Comment: Nope. a.show() actually is showing all send / receive packets history.

Comment: The whole scenario has been taken from here: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html. According with the official documentation that a.plot has to work but it doesn't.